# User security - cache password temporarily

Tags: php, security

I have a system that signs users up to a service. They register their account and choose their payment option at the same time. In order to integrate PayPal, the user must be redirected to PayPal, then return to my site. To do this, before redirecting to PayPal, I send all the user settings from the form to my backend to save it in a session. That is, fname, lname, email, and password (plain text of course).

The question is, how do I safely cache their password? I don't see in any way how a user could exploit this system, but there's always something...

Comment: Since they register an account, I'm guessing that you eventually will store their data in a database? Why not store it in the database directly instead of storing it in a session first? If not, then just hash the password before storing it in the session and save that hash into the database when you're done.

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter when you encrypt their password, just so long as you do. What's wrong with storing the encrypted password in the session?